# Allow Division by Zero with Python Dicts

Tags: python, divide-by-zero, dividebyzeroexception

I have two Python dictionaries containing broadly the same keys and I am trying to multiply the values of each key pair. One dictionary is slightly larger (due to containing additional keys that I want to ignore). The problem I am having is that in some instances zeros in the denominator is causing `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` - my question therefore is, how can i amend my script so that I perform the division, accepting that when zero is in the denominator the result will be '0'?

```
dict1 = {'A':1,'B':1,'C':2,'D':0}

dict2 = {'A':2,'B':2,'C':4,'D':0,'E':5}

myfunc = {k : v / dict2[k] for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2}
```

Comment: `if (k in dict 2 and v != 0)`

Comment: Something like: `multiply_func = {k : v / dict2[k] if dict2[k] != 0 else 0.0  for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2}`

Comment: You want to multiply each value why would you care about a ZeroDivisionError when you actually want to multiply. In case you actually mean divide: What result would you want to get when dividing by 0?

Comment: @hyred thanks for pointing this out. This was an oversight on my part as it later feeds into a separate multiplication function, but I appreciate this was not clear. I have now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below (the idea is to make sure that the denominator is not zero before we divide)

```
dict1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 0}
dict2 = {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 4, 'D': 0, 'E': 5}
myfunc = {k: v / dict2[k] if dict2[k] else 0 for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2}
print(myfunc)
```

output

```
{'A': 0.5, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.5, 'D': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myfunc = {k : (v / dict2[k] if dict2[k] else 0) for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2}
```

Comment: Apologies for those who saw the answer as I first posted it as I misinterpreted the question. Should be fixed now.